# Vectorized version of charToRaw with good performance

Tags: r, vectorization

I want to get a vector of raw bytes from a vector of character (to apply an encryption function that requires raw bytes as input on all values of a `data.table` column).

`charToRaw` does **not** work vectorized but processes only the first element of a vector:

```
x <- c("hello", "my", "world")
charToRaw(x)
# Warning message:
# In charToRaw(x) : argument should be a character vector of length 1
# all but the first element will be ignored
```

Is there a vectorized version of `charToRaw` offering a good performance? Why does base R's version not offer a vectorized version?

I know I could use `sapply` or `myapply` but I would end up with an internal loop over all rows...

**Edit 1:**
The result shall be a vector of the same size as 'x' with each element representing the raw bytes of the corresponding input element.

**Edit 2 + 3:**
My result should look like this (eg. as list)

```
x.raw
[1] 68 65 6c 6c 6f
[2] 6d 79
[3] 77 6f 72 6c 64
```

The problem is that R doesn't seem to support a vector of raw since `raw` itself is like vector of bytes... Any idea how to solve this?

**Edit 4 + 5:**

I have bench-marked the current proposals:

```
library(microbenchmark)
x <- sample(c("hello", "my", "world"), 1E6, TRUE)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  sapply_loop  = sapply(x, charToRaw),
  lapply_loop = lapply(x, charToRaw),
  vectorize_loop = { charToRawVec <-Vectorize(charToRaw, "x")
                     charToRawVec(x) },
  split = split(charToRaw(paste(x, collapse = "")), rep(seq_len(length(x)), nchar(x))),
  charToRaw_with_cpp = charToRaw_cpp(x),
  times = 5
)
```

The Rcpp solution from the answer of @Brian is 4 to 5 times faster than all other proposals (depending on the length of the strings):

```
Unit: milliseconds
               expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
        sapply_loop  761.6041 1149.7972 1153.1992 1202.6303 1306.2110 1345.7531     5
        lapply_loop  950.5337  972.1374 1172.4354 1134.9821 1300.4941 1504.0297     5
     vectorize_loop  951.9297  983.2725 1134.0204 1147.1145 1250.9649 1336.8201     5
              split 1201.5009 1275.7123 1409.3622 1425.0124 1529.5082 1615.0772     5
 charToRaw_with_cpp  111.7791  113.1815  313.5623  384.7327  466.9929  491.1253     5
```

Comment: An option using `split`: `split(charToRaw(paste(x, collapse = "")), rep(seq_len(length(x)), nchar(x)))` Not tested for performance though.

Comment: Excellent idea! Encodings with multi-byte representations for one character may make problems but still a good approach!

Comment: I fact I can't provide a `dput` of my output since I have no idea how to "embed" a vector of raw bytes in a vector :-(

Comment: Yes, a list would be a good result type. Good performance is my pain point (that is why I am asking for a "vectorized" version of `charToRaw`)

Comment: I have added `lapply` to the benchmark

Comment: @markus I tried a bunch of variations on that, but the `split` step was always a huge drag on performance. I think the only way to vectorize this and speed it up is Rcpp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a version that uses the [internal C source](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/5a156a0865362bb8381dcd69ac335f5174a4f60c/src/main/raw.c) for `charToRaw` without any of the error checking. The loop in `Rcpp` should be as fast as you can get, although I don't know if there's a better way to handle the memory allocation. As you can see, you don't get a statistically significant performance bump over `purrr::map`, but it is better than `sapply`.

```
library(Rcpp)

Rcpp::cppFunction('List charToRaw_cpp(CharacterVector x) {
  int n = x.size();
  List l = List(n);

  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    int nc = LENGTH(x[i]);
    RawVector ans = RawVector(nc);
    memcpy(RAW(ans), CHAR(x[i]), nc);
    l[i] = ans;
  }
  return l;
}')

# Random vector of 5000 strings of 5000 characters each
x <- unlist(purrr::rerun(5000, stringr::str_c(sample(c(letters, LETTERS), 5000, replace = T), collapse = "")))

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  sapply(x, charToRaw),
  purrr::map(x, charToRaw),
  charToRaw_cpp(x)
)
```

> ```
> Unit: milliseconds
>                     expr       min        lq      mean    median       uq       max neval cld
>     sapply(x, charToRaw) 60.337729 69.313684 76.908557 73.232365 78.99251 398.00732   100   b
> purrr::map(x, charToRaw)  8.849688  9.201125 17.117435  9.376843 10.09294 292.74068   100  a 
>         charToRaw_cpp(x)  5.578212  5.827794  7.998507  6.151864  7.10292  23.81905   100  a
> ```

With 1000 iterations you start to see an effect:

> ```
> Unit: milliseconds
>                     expr      min       lq      mean   median        uq      max neval cld
> purrr::map(x, charToRaw) 8.773802 9.191173 13.674963 9.425828 10.602676 302.7293  1000   b
>         charToRaw_cpp(x) 5.591585 5.868381  9.370648 6.119673  7.445649 295.1833  1000  a
> ```

## Edited note on performance:

I assumed you would see a bigger difference in performance with larger strings and vectors. But actually the biggest difference so far is for a 50-length vector of 50-character strings:

> ```
> Unit: microseconds
>                        expr    min     lq     mean median      uq     max neval cld
>        sapply(x, charToRaw) 66.245 69.045 77.44593 70.288 72.4650 862.110   500   b
>    purrr::map(x, charToRaw) 65.313 68.733 75.85236 70.599 72.7765 621.392   500   b
>           charToRaw_cpp(x)  4.666  6.221  7.47512  6.844  7.7770  58.159   500  a
> ```

Comment: I have added a benchmark of your answer to my question now (outperforming everything :-) - sorry for my delayed response. Excellent answer BTW (shows the strength of Rcpp and how easy it is if you know the R core internals ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Vectorize()` to complete this task:

```
x <- c("hello", "my", "world")
charToRawVec <- Vectorize(FUN = charToRaw, vectorize.args = "x")
charToRawVec(x)
```

Comment: Good idea. How about the performance? It the `Vectorize` function just a "loop" over the rows? Then I wouldn't expect a better performance than using `sapply` or `mapply`...

Comment: `Vectorize` is a wrapper for `mapply`, I think.

Comment: I have added my desired result in "plain words" but my problem is that R does not seem to support a vector of raw :-(

Comment: I have looked into the source code of "Vectorize", it is "just" a conveniance wrapper and does indeed use `mapply` internally...